# Query string parameters not working on my wordpress project

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on WordPress project. On my server php 7.0 running and the WordPress 4.9.4 installed. The issue that I am facing is: I have created a template file and I am trying to `print_r($_GET)` the query string variable from the url `?uid=213` then it returns Array() empty array.

When I tried the print_r statement on a different file on root folder then it works properly, but on functions.php or template file ( on WordPress pages )  its not working.

Can anybody tell me about this what is wrong with this?.
Below is the my htaccess file code:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    
    # END WordPress
```

Comment: can you please share your full url.

Comment: @RonakPatel  http://admin.mydemosite.com/user-detail?uid=163 this is demo url of my site.

Comment: "I have created a template file" Can you please specify teplate file name in your theme?

Comment: seems you have configure page url in htaccess. can you please post htaccess code?

Comment: @vel   Below is the my htaccess file code.   
# BEGIN WordPress
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: @vel I have also added the my htaccess code on question.

Comment: the user-details page not found?

Comment: @vel No I can access the page and all html and code except the query string values from the url.

Comment: `admin.mydemosite.com/user-detail?uid=163` this url not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

check your nginx config `nginx.conf`

and your location should be like this.

```
# WORDPRESS 
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```